# Collision detection not working on some parts of mesh

Tags: unity, collision-detection, blender

Racing game with a single mesh to act as a collider for all the track sides. Recently revised the mesh and now it is behaving strangely. The player correctly collides (bounces off) some parts, on other parts it is hit and miss whether the collider works and on others the player acts like there is no collider present at all.

I have checked that all the meshes normals are facing the correct direction and that there are no gaps in the mesh.

I have set the collisions on the player rigid body to be continuous.

Can anyone suggest what might be happening?

I was previously using the exact same technique but re-created the collider mesh to clean it up and upon importing from Blender into Unity the collider behaviour is now all over the place.

[image]

This picture shows part of the collider where the player just passes straight through the walls.

Car collider in Unity:
[image]

Track mesh collider in Unity:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us how your colliders (track and car) are configured in the inspector, and how your code moves your car?

Comment: I've added the collider inspector info. I can't understand how part of the mesh can be working as a collider and other parts aren't.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Are you using the mesh that the MeshCollider automatically creates or have you specified your own? Could it be that the collider is still using mesh data from before your revisions?